# Continous update of sensor data using while loop in python and tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop, tk-toolkit, nidaqmx

I am using NI instrument to read data and display it on GUI. Have used tkinter. But could not find a way to update the data using while loop.

```
import nidaqmx
import time
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()
while True:
    with nidaqmx.Task() as task:
        task.ai_channels.add_ai_voltage_chan("Dev1/ai0")
        print('1 Channel 1 Sample Read: ')
        data = task.read()
        sensor_value ='%.2f' % data #said sensor value
        master.minsize(width=400, height=400)
        w = Label(master, text=sensor_value) #shows as text in the window
        w.pack() #organizes widgets in blocks before placing them in the parent.          
        time.sleep(5)
        mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with Tkinter **we should avoid Threading, `while` loop with `root.update()`** it is not like we can't use them but not advisable instead use [`after(delay_ms, callback=None, *args)`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method) method provided by Tkinter itself for a reason.

Now to your code, there are few issues in your code.

1. In `while` loop you are ***creating a `Label` every 5 secs instead create one label and update the value*** of that label inside the loop with `w['text'] = '...'` or `w.configure(text='...')`.
2. ***Don't put `mainloop` inside the loop***, instead call it in the last line with the instance of the main window in your case `master` (`master.mainloop()`).
3. Same with `master.minsize(width=400, height=400)`, ***you don't have to tell the master window every 5 sec to set the minimum size to 400x400 it should be called once*** if not decide to change the minimum size to different geomentry.

Your code should look like this.

```py
import nidaqmx
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
master.minsize(width=400, height=400)
w = Label(master) #shows as text in the window
w.pack() #organizes widgets in blocks before placing them in the parent.   

def run():
    with nidaqmx.Task() as task:
        task.ai_channels.add_ai_voltage_chan("Dev1/ai0")
        print('1 Channel 1 Sample Read: ')
        data = task.read()
        w['text'] = '%.2f' % data #said sensor value
    master.after(5000, run)

run() # run the function once.
master.mainloop()
```

This should be the right way of doing this and as i couldn't run your code if anything doesn't work, let me know otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
import time
from tkinter import *
import nidaqmx

master = Tk()

def test():
    while True:
        with nidaqmx.Task() as task:
            task.ai_channels.add_ai_voltage_chan("Dev1/ai0")
            print('1 Channel 1 Sample Read: ')
            data = task.read()
            sensor_value = '%.2f' % data  # said sensor value
            
            w['text'] = sensor_value
            master.update()
            time.sleep(2)

w = Label(master)
w.pack()
btn = Button(text="Start read from sensor", command=test)
btn.pack()
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll likely need a second thread to poll the sensor.

```
import nidaqmx
import time
import threading
from tkinter import *


stop_signal = threading.Event()


def read_loop():
    with nidaqmx.Task() as task:
        task.ai_channels.add_ai_voltage_chan("Dev1/ai0")
        while True:
            data = task.read()
            label["text"] = "%.2f" % data

            # Wait for the signal, or 5 seconds
            if stop_signal.wait(timeout=5):
                break  # If the signal was set, break


# Build window
master = Tk()
master.minsize(width=400, height=400)
label = Label(master, text="")
label.pack()

# Set up & start reading thread
threading.Thread(target=read_loop).start()

try:
    # Enter Tk main loop
    mainloop()
finally:
    # Clean up afterwards
    stop_signal.set()
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that `mainloop()` is blocking, so `time.sleep()` is useless as you won't get back to the `task.read()` line.
Consider using the Thread module from the threading lib importing it like this:

```
from threading import Thread
```

or using a button to refresh the value as someone else suggested you.